# Handling Processing-Intensive Event-Actions in Jython

Tags: python, events, jython

I have some long-term processes and such that must occur at given button-presses or other events in a Jython GUI I am creating.

In such situations, it seems the best option is to make a separate thread to run the called method/function in when the event happens.

What is the best way to do this? import Threading and have a class that I initialize and run when actionPerformed? Use invokelater? It seems there are a lot of ways to go about this, but would work best in the Jython-Swing environment and be the 'fastest'?

```
start = JButton( "Analyze", actionPerformed = self.do_analysis )

def do_analysis(self):
    ...
    Large Time Consuming Task
    ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure that jython has the same problem, but in C Python, you would run into a problem with the GIL or Global Interpreter Lock.  This will mean that when your background thread is running, the GUI thread cannot start (even if it is queued to run on another core). You click a button and nothing happens :(

To get round this, I would split the long running process into short steps that can be run on an event, and queue up the event to start the next step as the current step ends. Then the GUI will be able to run between steps if it needs to. The shorter you make the steps, the more responsive the GUI will be - 50ms to 100ms should be OK.

This approach has the nice side effect that you don't need to worry about threads, locking, message queueing or anything. You can try and add these to a GUI but the GUI events and the threads can fight, leading to some very strange and hard to debug errors.

As for the "fastest", this is probably the lowest overhead for shorter background tasks. If you create a new process to run the background task (very heavy overhead in Windows) then it will run faster becasue it has its own core, but the start/stop overhead is high.

Answer (score 0):

This is a situation where you will get the best results by remembering that Jython is running on the JVM. Jython has full access to Java classes, so use the Java threading API to set up a separate computation thread. And if the CPU load is high enough that using more cores would help, Java (the jvm) will take care of that by itself.

In some circumstances, with long running processes, people have used `jstack -l` to get the `nids` of running threads, and then use `taskset` to set the CPU affinity. The JVM `nid` is in hex and is the PID of the Linux process corresponding to a thread. Other OSes may have similar capabilities.

In general, it is not necessary to do anything other than to make your Jython multithreaded. If you use the Python threading module you don't have access to the full Java threading featureset, but it does use JVM threads under the hood. Just remember to limit your access to global variables or you will end up recreating the Global Interpreter Lock. The Queue module can help with this.